# Хранение аватарок в base64 в файлах

Tags: base64, php

Всем привет!

Как насчёт того, чтобы при загрузке файлов фото конвертировать в base64, и сохранять в этот же файл код, а потом в шаблоне подгружать аватарки с помощью file_get_contents()?

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?=file_get_content($user->avatar);?>">
```

Вес аватарок не более 50-70 кб, размеры 200х200. Будет и такое, что 50-100 аватарок на странице.

Есть ли в этом смысл?

Comment: @chuikoff

> Будет и такое что 50-100 аватарок на странице

ssd выдержит, а вот обычный винт может долго эти сто файлов искать (пускай даже 5мс на поиск и чтение - 500 мс в сумме), причем если делать обычный src="путь", то искать эти файлы будет браузер, и делать это он будет **после** загрузки страницы, в то время как в этом случае страница **не загрузится, пока все файлы не будут найдены**. Это можно обойти кэшированием этого контента, но проще будет использовать обычный подход.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Современные ОС (в смысле Linux :) используют свободную оперативную память для кеширования дисковых операций, так что при наличии излишков RAM с диска аватарки читаться будут только один раз. В общем, об этом, на мой взгляд, можно особо не заморачиваться.

В данном случае интереснее другой кэш, кэш на клиенте. GET запросы кешируются клиентом (если сервер возвращает соответствующие заголовки). При правильных заголовках кеширования сервера клиент, при повторном посещении страницы, даже не станет запрашивать аватары, просто покажет их из кеша.

Data url вставки скачиваются всегда, ведь это просто часть страницы. А ведь 100 аватаров по 70 Кб это 7 Мб. К тому-же есть любители блокировать adblock-ом gif-аватары (что-бы не отвлекали), или вообще запрещать загрузку картинок, для экономии трафика. В вашем варианте они обломятся.

Если речь идёт о форуме, то все более менее активные форумчане быстро закешируют аватарки друг друга.